# Clojure/Ring: Using the ring jetty adapter, large requests give me a 413: FULL HEAD error.

Tags: clojure, jetty, limit, ring

Using Ring's Jetty adapter, if my request is too large I get a 413: FULL HEAD error.  I tracked it down to a property called headerbuffersize, but when I try to set it in the run-jetty call, I still get the 413's.  Is there a better way to control jetty config from Ring?

```
(ring/run-jetty
 (var app)
 {:port port :join? false
  :headerbuffersize 1048576})
```

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
(def header-buffer-size 1048576)

(def config
  {:host  "example.com"
   :port  8080
   ; join? false ; and any other options...
   :configurator (fn [jetty]
                   (doseq [connector (.getConnectors jetty)]
                     (.setHeaderBufferSize connector
                                           header-buffer-size)))
   })
```

Comment: That most certainly does work!  I see now, with a reference to jetty we can do whatever configuration we need.  Thanks!

Comment: Someone stated that in recent versions of jetty you should use `setRequestHeaderSize` instead of `setHeaderBufferSize`. If that is the case, feel free to include this information as an addendum.