# Can you set the size limit of a post request in header?

Tags: http, post, clojure, noir

I'm trying to make a post request to my noir server but I have too many parameters and the server just responds with 413 status code. I was wondering if I could raise the character limit for the post request. I read it's possible with other services like [What is the size limit of a post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request?rq=1) and [Clojure/Ring: Using the ring jetty adapter, large requests give me a 413: FULL HEAD error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285096/clojure-ring-using-the-ring-jetty-adapter-large-requests-give-me-a-413-full-h)

Thanks!

Comment: You probably know this, but just in case -- Noir has basically been deprecated by its maintainers, who now recommend using Ring + Compojure directly. Substantial parts which are maintained and can be used à la carte are available in [lib-noir](https://github.com/noir-clojure/lib-noir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`noir.server/start` accepts a map of options as a second argument (which is itself optional). If this map contains an entry with a key of `:jetty-options`, the value at that key is passed as the options argument to `ring.adapter.jetty/run-jetty`.

So, you can say something like

```
(server/start 8080 {:jetty-options {:configurator ...}})
```

where the value at the `:configurator` key is as described in my answer to the [Clojure/Ring: Using the ring jetty adapter, large requests give me a 413: FULL HEAD error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285096/clojure-ring-using-the-ring-jetty-adapter-large-requests-give-me-a-413-full-h) question you link to:

```
;;; reproducing here for convenience
(fn [jetty]
  (doseq [connector (.getConnectors jetty)]
    (.setHeaderBufferSize connector header-buffer-size)))
```

(`header-buffer-size` being the name of a Var storing a value you're happy with).