# 413 Full HEAD error

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, servlets

i have made a dynamic blog engine, where multiple authors can publish articles.

the author goes to a page where he inputs the 'article' 'description' and 'the whole article' in three `<textarea>` 
Then i store all the values in 3 variables and store it in the database via an ajax based request.

The Problem: 
The HttpServerRequest is too large and it gives a 413 FULL Head error, and the request doesnt get through.

The Code:

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <h4 class="text-left">Title:</h4>
        <textarea id="title" rows="2" cols="" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <h4 class="text-left">Description:</h4>
        <textarea id="description" rows="5" cols="" ></textarea>
        <br />
        <h4 class="text-left">Article:</h4>
        <textarea id="article" rows="40" cols="" onkeyup="replaceWordChars(this.value)"></textarea>
        <br />

        <div class="publish btn">Publish</div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
```

The Script:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.publish').click(function(){
            title = $('#title').val();
            description = $('#description').val();
            article = $('#article').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:       "get",
                url:        "/articles",
                data:       {action:'add', title:title, description:description, article:article},
                success:    function(code)
                {
                            alert("published"); 
                            window.location="dashboard.jsp";
                }

            }).error(function(){ alert("error"); })
            .complete(function(){ alert("complete"); });

        });

    });
    </script>
```

The ERROR:

> "NetworkError: 413 FULL head - http:///articles?action=add&title=blah&..........gs.%0A%0A&userId=1"

The Question:

Is there an alternate way to send a big server request??
I also read on google that we can change the size, to match huge requests?

Answers are preferred in java, HTML, javascript (or) jQuery

***EDIT*** I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093392/can-you-set-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request-in-header?lq=1) that we can set the size limit of post request in header? How can i do it in GAE?

Comment: @user2511414 No, that's overkill for a single request. GAE *doesn't even* support websockets, anyway.

Comment: I haven't seen sending big data with get method! maybe you need to post data as `POST` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use HEAD or GET for large parameters. Those should only be used for idempotent requests(repeating it doesn't break anything), and requests that only retrieve data(i.e. searching or filtering a product database) anyway.

Use a POST request instead:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.publish').click(function(){
            title = $('#title').val();
            description = $('#description').val();
            article = $('#article').val();

            $.ajax({
                type:       "post",
                url:        "/articles",
                data:       {action:'add', title:title, description:description, article:article},
                // .... skipped unchanged lines
    </script>
```

This is a one-line change.

On the server, make sure you use `doPost()` instead of `doGet()` in the servlet. You can get parameters in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

In my case HEADER was full because cookie value was too large for SESSIONID. I deleted all cookie for that site and it worked.